# Trying to Filter JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to filter JSON with JSON.filter() but my code is wrong, I've tried a few variations and all have failed. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
;(async function () {
    const result = await transform(xml, template);
    const prettyStr = await prettyPrint(xml, { indentSize: 4});
    const filterActive = JSON.filter(result, products.active === 'true');
    fs.writeFileSync('./temp/converted.json', JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Here's the JSON that's output without the filter:

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "id": "60000000425",
            "sku": "0135363004",
            "active": "false",
            "brand": "BROWNING",
            "description": "725 HUNTER 12G 28\" M/C",
            "price": "1719.0000",
            "category": "1",
            "department": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": "60000000000",
            "sku": "00100",
            "active": "true",
            "brand": "",
            "description": "ELEY 22 TENEX",
            "price": "0.2600",
            "category": "8",
            "department": "3"
        },
```

Comment: what error are you getting exactly ?

Comment: There no such method call `filter` in JOSN object.
I guess you are looking for `JSON.parse()`

Comment: I just get '[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.705 seconds' in the VSCode console.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
const filterActive = result.products.filter(({active}) => active === 'true');
```

```js
var result = {
  "products": [{
      "id": "60000000425",
      "sku": "0135363004",
      "active": "false",
      "brand": "BROWNING",
      "description": "725 HUNTER 12G 28\" M/C",
      "price": "1719.0000",
      "category": "1",
      "department": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "60000000000",
      "sku": "00100",
      "active": "true",
      "brand": "",
      "description": "ELEY 22 TENEX",
      "price": "0.2600",
      "category": "8",
      "department": "3"
    }
  ]
};

const filterActive = result.products.filter(({active}) => active === 'true');

console.log(filterActive);
```

Comment: Thanks, interestingly this works here but not in my local code. I need to play some more.

Answer (score 1):

The result might be a string. 
Have you tried parsing the result `JSON.parse(result)` before doing the filtering ?
And you need to do the filtering like below.

```
const filterActive = result.products.filter(({active}) => active === 'true');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can only filter an array

change your code to

```
;(async function () {
    const result = await transform(xml, template);
    const prettyStr = await prettyPrint(xml, { indentSize: 4});
    const filterActive = result.products.filter((product)=>product.active === true);
    fs.writeFileSync('./temp/converted.json', JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Comment: This isn't working for me either, although I think it should.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var json_data = {
                   "products":[
                      {
                         "id":"60000000425",
                         "sku":"0135363004",
                         "active":"false",
                         "brand":"BROWNING",
                         "description":"725 HUNTER 12G 28\" M/C",
                         "price":"1719.0000",
                         "category":"1",
                         "department":"1"
                      },
                      {
                         "id":"60000000000",
                         "sku":"00100",
                         "active":"true",
                         "brand":"",
                         "description":"ELEY 22 TENEX",
                         "price":"0.2600",
                         "category":"8",
                         "department":"3"
                      }
                   ]
                };


    const products = json_data.products;
    console.log('*****************');
    console.log('Products', products);
    console.log('*****************');
    const filtered_products = products.filter((prod)=> prod.active === 'true');
    console.table(filtered_products);
```